# Importing an Emotion style partial from a separate module yields improper results, but importing from file works

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, styled-components, emotion

I'm using Webpack and Babel and I have quite a bit of experience, but I can't figure out what might be going on here. The main project and the module I'm trying to import from are both within a single Lerna monorepo and both have identical `.babelrc` configurations. The Babel configuration includes the `babel-plugin-emotion`.

Here's the style partial in question:

```js
import { css } from 'emotion';
export const zoomPartial = css`
  zoom: 0.9;
`;
```

**When I import the partial like this, I get the proper output:**

```js
import { zoomPartial } from './partials';
```

[image]

**But when I import like this, I get an improper output:**

```js
import { zoomPartial } from 'partials-module';
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was importing `css` from 'emotion' instead of from '@emotion/core'